# Facebook shows wrong Author when sharing Link of Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Whenever I post a link of a post from my blog on Facebook, Facebook shows the wrong author.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The meta tag in my header.php has another author in it.

```
<meta name="author" content="MYAUTHORNAME">
```

I searched the web and tried to add this:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/MYSITE" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/MYSITE" />
```

But still no effect. I don't know where the author tag on Facebook is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you dont have a publisher meta:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/fareedzakaria" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/cnn" />
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl

Also check if your code is valid using this: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ insert the url and press "fetch new scrape information" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: It works now thanks. Facebook is crawling the data as it seems. I thought Facebook would scrape the data live but apperently not. After a forced crawl it changed the author.